# WinSCP script hangs when connecting to host

Tags: script, batch-file, winscp

I've batch script that runs winscp with script, and sometimes WinSCP hangs when is "Connecting to host".

Is it possible to set timeout that WinSCP stops trying to connect and shuts it's self after x seconds when cannot connect?

Comment: I had a similar issue with WinSCP a few years ago which led to my discovery of the [WinSCP forums](http://winscp.net/forum/index.php) where any of the threads are answered by the main developer himself.

Comment: Does it "hang" or does it keep re-trying to connect?

Comment: @Martin Pikryl, wscp prompts Connecting to host and waits infinitely.

Comment: Please include a WinSCP session log file.

Answer (score 1):

On you open command you can set a timeout parameter

```
-timeout=<sec>
```

**Example:**

```
open sftp://martin:mypassword@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" -timeout=30
```

Answer (score 1):

A default timeout is 15 seconds. You can change it using the `-timeout` switch of the [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open). Though in some cases, Windows does not respect the timeout and may use longer (or shorter).

When a connection fails (or times out), WinSCP will retry the connection. In the [default "batch" mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option#batch), WinSCP will keep re-trying for up to 2 minutes. In an interactive mode, it keeps trying forever.

You can change the limit using the [`option reconnecttime <sec>` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option).

Examples:

```
option batch abort
option reconnecttime 60
open sftp://user@example.com/ -timeout=15
```

Comment: When using `option reconnectime 60` I get `Unknown option 'reconnectime'.`.  Try instead using `reconnecttime`.

Comment: @ArvoBowen Thanks, I've corrected my answer.